# Can I access individual list item during LINQ Join?

Tags: linq, join, c#-4.0

I have two lists. I want to join them through LINQ. I hope below code snippet should give the idea, what I am trying to achieve.

```
var lst = from param in Parameters join rule in parameterMap.MappingRules on param.Name equals rule.CompareLHS(param.Name) where rule.Compare<double>(param.Value.Value) select new { param.Name, param.Value };
```

Above statement doesn't get compile as I am trying to use 'param' on both sides of 'equals'.

Is there any possibility that I can access 1st list individual item (here param) again while comparing with 2nd list individual item like this(**param.Name equals rule.CompareLHS(param.Name)**)?

Comment: Which part doesn't compile? The Join? The Where, or the Select? Can you give the parts of your classes that are involved in this statement? What is your goal in this statement: you want the combination of all parameters and rules where the name of the paremeter is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the inner join to a cross join with a condition:

```
var lst = from param in Parameters
          from rule in parameterMap.MappingRules
          where param.Name == rule.CompareLHS(param.Name)
          where rule.Compare<double>(param.Value.Value)
          select new { param.Name, param.Value };
```